# Do I need "about" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis

> No, it couldn't be. Then investigating (about) those murderers had been useless?

Do I need *about* in this case? Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/investigate) and [The FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/investigate) agree that it should be ***investigate something***, not ***<del>investigate about something</del>***, so no preposition in this case, please.

Your confusion might stem from synonyms verbs that require prepositions like *enquire about* or *look into*.

Comment: Correct! In the same way, 'discuss about' is quite wrong, but commonly observed among non-native speakers. Either you 'talk about' or simply 'discuss'. 'About' in 'Discuss about' is redundant.